# Scipy fsolve: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, scipy

I did array  `M = np.zeros(int(n + 1))`  (here is the same problem with *LR*  array) and after *for loop* is error: **setting an array element with a sequence**.
 So i changed it to `M = np.zeros(int(n + 1), dtype=object)` (same LR) and the problem was gone, but my loop did not append values to M array.

```py
T_max = 0.5 * v_PM(Me) * RTOD #max wall angle
DT = (90 - T_max) - np.fix(90 - T_max) #DT is delta angle
n = T_max * 2

T = np.zeros(int(n + 1))
M = np.zeros(int(n + 1))
P = np.zeros(int(n + 1))
RR = np.zeros(int(n + 1))
LR = np.zeros(int(n + 1))
SL = np.zeros(int(n + 1))

#Points on axis P[m]
for m in range(int(n+1)): 
    T[m] = (DT + m) * DTOR  
    #Mach from T(i) using T(i) = v_PM (FALSE POSITION)
    x_int = np.array([1,1.01*Me])
    func = lambda x: T[m] - v_PM(x)
    M[m] = fsolve(func, x_int) 
    P[m] = 0 + TR * np.tan(T[m]) #X-AXIS POINTS
    #RR SLOPES
    RR[m] = -TR / P[m]
    #LR slopes
    LR[m] = np.tan(T[m] + np.arcsin(1 / M[m]))
    SL[m] = -RR[m] 


print(M)
print('\n')
print(LR)
```

Here is the error without `dtype=object`

```py
     17     x_int = np.array([1,1.01*Me])
     18     func = lambda x: T[m] - v_PM(x)
---> 19     M[m] = fsolve(func, x_int)
     20     P[m] = 0 + TR * np.tan(T[m]) #X-AXIS POINTS
     21     #RR SLOPES

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

And here is with solution with added`dtype=object` in 
`M = np.zeros(int(n + 1), dtype=object) LR = np.zeros(int(n + 1), dtype=object)` before *for loop*.

```
It is M:
[array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([2.8779873, 2.8779873])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([1.        , 3.33794218])
 array([1.        , 3.33794218]) array([-3.19310305,  3.19310305])
 array([3.24956731, 3.24956731]) array([-3.30728795,  3.30728795])]


It is LR:
[array([-165.10795432,    0.32067489]) array([-42.52750448,   0.34003326])
 array([-24.39852658,   0.3596228 ]) array([-17.09899011,   0.37945982])
 array([-13.15518587,   0.39956138]) array([-10.68434265,   0.4199453 ])
 array([-8.99024399,  0.44063026]) array([-7.75572025,  0.46163587])
 array([-6.81559333,  0.48298276]) array([-6.07537179,  0.50469263])
 array([-5.47709289,  0.52678841]) array([-4.98322637,  0.5492943 ])
 array([-4.56840025,  0.57223595]) array([-4.2148461 ,  0.59564052])
 array([-3.90974917,  0.61953687]) array([-3.64363454,  0.64395571])
 array([-3.40934552,  0.66892974]) array([-3.20137548,  0.69449386])
 array([-3.0154182 ,  0.72068539]) array([-2.84805756,  0.74754427])
 array([-2.69654888,  0.77511335]) array([-2.55866161,  0.80343866])
 array([-2.43256432,  0.83256974]) array([-2.3167392 ,  0.86256001])
 array([-2.20991764,  0.89346716]) array([-2.11103112,  0.9253536 ])
 array([-2.01917319,  0.95828702]) array([-1.93356984,  0.99234093])
 array([-1.85355617,  1.02759536]) array([-1.77855775,  1.06413759])
 array([-1.70807574,  1.10206303]) array([-1.64167484,  1.14147619])
 array([-1.57897344,  1.18249186]) array([-1.51963557,  1.22523639])
 array([-1.46336428,  1.26984918]) array([-1.40989607,  1.31648452])
 array([-1.35899634,  1.36531357]) array([-1.31045547,  1.41652678])
 array([-1.26408561,  1.47033676]) array([-1.21971784,  1.52698154])
 array([-1.17719989,  1.58672857]) array([-1.13639408,  1.64987944])
 array([-1.09717563,  1.7167755 ]) array([-1.05943111,  1.78780468])
 array([-1.02305722,  1.86340977]) array([-0.98795964,  1.94409846])
 array([-0.95405204,  2.03045575]) array([2.4357523, 2.4357523])
 array([-0.8894966,  2.2229984]) array([-0.85870903,  2.33089833])
 array([-0.82883076,  2.44795068]) array([-0.79980469,  2.57545261])
 array([-0.7715779 ,  2.71495777]) array([0.70271638, 3.00570635])
 array([3.12770176, 3.12770176]) array([0.77421175, 3.25997748])]
D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:4: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.
```

I think there might be problem with fsolve, but im totally beginner so im not sure. Also i couldnt find solution on the other sites.

Comment: Evidently the `fsolve` solution is a 2 element array.  You can't put that into an element of an array that expects single numbers.  You can put that into an array that accepts 'objects'.  And alternative might be to initial `M=np.zeros((n,2))` and assign `M[m,:] = fsolve(...)`.  That is, put the solution into a 'row' of `M`.

Comment: ```M=np.zeros((n,2)``` helped, but  ```M[m,:] = fsolve(...)``` nothing changed. I want to assign a new value to the first element in M.

With ```M[m,:]``` or only ```M[m]``` answer is the same  for both cases.